# Azure devOps - run a Az Security Benchmark & Display the results

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-policy

I have an Azure devOps release pipeline that creates Azure resources.

After Az Resource creation I want to force run the "Azure Security Benchmark" built policy.

I have written the following that works...

```
try {

$rg  = $(solution-rg-name)
$sub = $(subscription-id)
    
Write-Host "Get-AzPolicySetDefinition"  
# Security Benchmark built-in policy = 1f3afdf9-d0c9-4c3d-847f-89da613e70a8
$PolicySet = Get-AzPolicySetDefinition -Name "1f3afdf9-d0c9-4c3d-847f-89da613e70a8" -Subscription $sub -ErrorAction Stop

Write-Host "New-AzPolicyAssignment"
New-AzPolicyAssignment -Name "Security Benchmark $rg" -PolicySetDefinition $PolicySet -Scope "/subscriptions/$sub/resourceGroups/$rg" -ErrorAction Stop

Write-Host "Start-AzPolicyComplianceScan"
$job = Start-AzPolicyComplianceScan -AsJob -ResourceGroupName $rg
$job | Wait-Job

Write-Host "Get-AzPolicyStateSummary"
Get-AzPolicyStateSummary -SubscriptionId $sub -ResourceGroupName $rg -ErrorAction Stop      

}
catch {
    Write-Host " ERROR "
    Write-Host "An error occurred: $($_.Exception.Message)"
}
finally {
    Write-Host "Cleanup or finalization steps"
}
```

Is there a way to retrieve the output (non-compliant) from running 'Start-AzPolicyComplianceScan' (Azure Security Benchmark) and display in a 'nice' within the Az devOps pipeline run?

Maybe there is a third part devOps task type you have used for a similar thing?

Nb: "Get-AzPolicyStateSummary" doesn't give what i need.